# Sacar datos de Json Y Js

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, json

Llevo rato intentando sacar los datos del **JSON** desdes un **Js** y no encuentro manera. Pongo el ejemplo de uno de los **JSON** y el **HTML** que me es imposible de recorrer.

> CODIGO HTML Y JS

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> STATION BSL</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Fredy Ortiz Toto - Fredy Ortiz">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        console.log();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "Get/GetHistory.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {

                    $.each(result, function(i, value) {
                        if (value[0] == "Version") {
                            document.getElementById("Version").innerHTML = value[1];
                        } else if (value[0] == "PIC") {
                            document.getElementById("PIC").innerHTML = value[2];
                        } else if (value[0] == "Turno") {
                            document.getElementById("Turno").innerHTML = value[3];
                        } else if (value[0] == "Comments") {
                            document.getElementById("Comments").innerHTML = value[4];
                        } else if (value[0] == "Update_Time") {
                            document.getElementById("Update_Time").innerHTML = value[5];
                        } else {
                            alert("Error en el Query");
                        }


                    });

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);

                }

            });


        });
    </script>



    <script>
        function ventanaNueva(documento) {
            // mostramos la ventana centrada
            window.open('formulario.php', target = 'blank', 'width=' + anchura + ',height=' + altura + ',top=' + y + ',left=' + x + ',toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,directories=no,resizable=no');
        }

        function arrastrar() {
            anuncio.moveTo(200, 100);
            anuncio.focus();
        }
        // definimos la anchura y altura de la ventana
        var altura = 380;
        var anchura = 630;

        // calculamos la posicion x e y para centrar la ventana
        var y = parseInt((window.screen.height / 2) - (altura / 2));
        var x = parseInt((window.screen.width / 2) - (anchura / 2));
    </script>

</head>


<body>


    <!-- Cabecera -->
    <header>

        <div id="contenedor">
            <div id="cabecera">
                <h1>STATION BSL</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="fondomenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Index.html">STATION BSL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Station.html">HISTORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="formulario.php">REGISTER DATA</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <!-- Contenido -->
    <section>


        <center>
            <table class="grilla" id="tablajson">
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Online Status</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>Station name ID</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th>PIC</th>
                        <th>Turno</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                        <th>Update Time</th>
                        <th>Update Version</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>10.49.30.198</td>
                        <td>F4-198</td>
                        <td><label style="font-size:20px" id="Version"> </label> </td>
                        <td><label style="font-size:20px" id="PIC"> </label></td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Turno"> </label></td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Comments"> </label></td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Update_Time"> </label></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="UPDATE" onclick="ventanaNueva('formulario.php')" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>10.49.30.199</td>
                        <td>F4-199</td>
                        <td>21.3.9006.0 </td>
                        <td> <label style="font-size:20px" id="Version"> </label></td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="UPDATE" onclick="ventanaNueva('formulario.php')" /></td>
                    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </center>




    </section>


    <br />
    <br />
    <!-- Pie de pagina -->
    <div class="footer-basic"></div>
    <footer class="clearfix">
        <div class="row">
            <center>
                <p><img src="imagenes/logo30.png" alt="" width="10%"></p>
                <FONT COLOR="white"> TE Department, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</FONT>
            </center>

        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

> **codigo PHP Y JSON**

```
<?php
//Creamos la conexión
$conn=mysqli_connect("10.49.30.28","wmxte","password","monica");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
//generamos la consulta
$sql="SELECT `Version`, `PIC`, `Turno`, `Comments`, `Update_Time` FROM `tbl_stacionbsl` WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3','4','5','7','8')";


mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) die();
$clientes = array(); //creamos un array

$tabla = "";
$i=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 

{ 
     
           $clientes[]=array(0=>$row['Version'],1=>$row['PIC'], 2=>$row['Turno'],3=>$row['Comments'], 4=>$row['Update_Time']);
    

}
    


echo json_encode($clientes);



?>
```

Llevo rato intentando sacar los datos del **JSON** desdes un **Js** y no encuentro manera. Pongo el ejemplo de uno de los **JSON** y el **HTML** que me es imposible de recorrer.

Mi intención es colocar en los distintas tablas (Version,PIC , etc) la información extraída del JSON. Obviamente habría que recorrerlo para extraer toda la información, pero soy incapaz hasta de extraer el primer elemento, creo que me esta molestando el nombre del array. Me podrian ayudar a checarlo,

ya que esto me estadando mucha precupacion.

Comment: Hola @Ortiztoto12, bienvenido a StackOverflow, por favor revisa en [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Estas mandando un ejemplo, pero no estas indicando que haz intentado para resolver tu problema y los errores que te aparecieron en el proceso.

Answer (score 1):

lo primero que veo es que el arreglo de salida de PHP tiene la forma:

```
['<Version>', '<PIC>', '<Turno>', ...]
```

- Donde <> es el valor de cada campo de la tabla.

Y después lo intentas leer como:

```
['Version|PIC|Turno', '<Version>']
```

Lo primero que recomiendo para poder revisar que es lo que está llegando es agregar `console.debug(result)` al inicio de tu function `success` en el llamado de `ajax`.
Para algo mas profesional o complejo puedes usar [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) o [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) para hacer pruebas.

Por otro lado la estructura de tu arreglo `$clientes` es recomendable que sea:

```
['Version' => '<Version>', 'PIC' => '<PIC>', 'Turno' => '<Turno>', ...]
```

Para que sea un objeto de `JSON`.